# Why java accepts "....." as a valid directory?

Tags: java, file

I am using Java files in one of my application.

```
File file = new File("c:\\users\\......");
System.out.println(file.isDirectory());
```

I don't have a directory or file in the name of "......"  in my users directory, but still file.isDirectory returns true, why?

Why does this happen? And how can I avoid this?

Comment: even exists() returns true

Comment: Can't reproduce this (on Linux with JDK 17). Maybe on Windows the rules of the filesystem are different?

Comment: According to [this MS blog post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jeremykuhne/path-normalization) "A segment of three periods (or more) doesn't hit any of these rules and is actually a valid file/directory name." That suggests that what you have is simply the name of a file and/or directory. A weird, but valid one. Did you by chance actually *create* that directory somehow?

Comment: `file.getCanonicalPath()` returns `c:\users`. Might be that the canonical path is what it actually checks under the hood

Comment: @JoachimSauer And the next paragraph says: “If the path doesn't end in a separator, all trailing periods and spaces (…) will be removed.”  So it would appear that a file’s base name cannot consist of only consecutive periods in Windows.

Comment: @VGR: but the previous paragraph starts with "If a segment ends in a *single* period" (emphasis theirs!). Also it would be weird that they call out three or more periods as valid if the next paragraph implied the opposite.

Comment: Also: since these rules are quite arcane, there is a non-zero chance that Java doesn't apply the exact same rules as Windows and/or that those rules are not immutable and have been changed. So I wouldn't rule out a Java bug or even some intentional deviation from the strict Windows rules.